# How to set up page speed logging for google analytics in analytics.js

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics.js

Google released the new `Analytics.js` (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/). I would like to use it, and I already have everyting set up just fine, apart from site speed.

In the "old" `ga.js` you could do this with

```
_gaq.push(['_setSiteSpeedSampleRate', 50]);
```

This would set it so 50% of the visitors would report sitespeed to analytics.

However, for the new `analytics.js` I cannot get it to work. I tried the following 2:

```
ga('send','setSiteSpeedSampleRate',50);
ga('setSiteSpeedSampleRate',50);
```

But no results. Any ideas?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Ah, I found my answer. It now has to be set in the create method like this:

```
ga('create', 'UA-39262824-7', {'siteSpeedSampleRate': 100});
```

There are more fields that can be used there, found it here: [Google Analytics Site Speed Sample Rate](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#siteSpeedSampleRate)

Comment: +1 for being the north star on a sea of decaying google documentation.

Comment: How do you combine that if you are using the code recommended for cross-domain tracking: `ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'myTopLevelDomain.com');`

Comment: @Liam I guess `ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'myTopLevelDomain.com',{'siteSpeedSampleRate': 100});`

Comment: @Liam ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'myTopLevelDomain.com',{'siteSpeedSampleRate': 100}); worked or not?

Comment: @piyushnp I think so, unfortunately I can't check it now. You could check it by adding tracking code for a second property to the same site, e.g. ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-**ZZ**', 'myTopLevelDomain.com',{'siteSpeedSampleRate': 100}); leave it running for a few days, then compare the reports for the two properties.

Comment: @piyushnp Yes it works fine. I just tested it. The GA debug Chrome extension might may show you an error, but you [can ignore it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956326/google-analytics-site-speed-with-sitespeedsamplerate-set-has-javascript-error/20888549#20888549). Don't need to wait either. Results are real-time these days.