# Google Analytics Site Speed with siteSpeedSampleRate set has JavaScript error

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I want to use Google Analytics to monitor site speed. I pasted the code below in my HTML page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x', 'domain.com', {'siteSpeedSampleRate': 100});
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

In order to test it in my localhost, I use `analytics_debug.js` instead of `analytics.js`, `UA-xxxxxxxx-x` as the real id, and `domain.com` as the real domain name.  `siteSpeedSampleRate` is used to set the sample rate (see [this link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#siteSpeedSampleRate)).

However, when my HTML page is visited, this JavaScript error happens when calling `ga('send', 'pageview')`:

```
Missing required field '"timingCategory"' for hit of type '"timing"' analytics_debug.js:8
log analytics_debug.js:8
O analytics_debug.js:7
b analytics_debug.js:15
Ec analytics_debug.js:15
nc analytics_debug.js:21
gc.(anonymous function).execute analytics_debug.js:19
ad.(anonymous function).send analytics_debug.js:45
Y.b.(anonymous function) analytics_debug.js:32
(anonymous function) analytics_debug.js:46
Sc analytics_debug.js:33
(anonymous function) analytics_debug.js:33
Missing required field '"timingVar"' for hit of type '"timing"' analytics_debug.js:8
log analytics_debug.js:8
O analytics_debug.js:7
b analytics_debug.js:15
Ec analytics_debug.js:15
nc analytics_debug.js:21
gc.(anonymous function).execute analytics_debug.js:19
ad.(anonymous function).send analytics_debug.js:45
Y.b.(anonymous function) analytics_debug.js:32
(anonymous function) analytics_debug.js:46
Sc analytics_debug.js:33
(anonymous function) analytics_debug.js:33
```

Answer (score 3):

As of 2014.01.02 this error message is standard in analytics_debug.js when it is sending a pagespeed timing beacon. Your code is fine / working corectly.

Comment: Annoying. They should fix it!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following syntax:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-Y', {'cookieDomain': 'example.com', 'siteSpeedSampleRate': 100});
```

Pass all option parameters within the `{}` and you should be fine.

To test it on local host set the `cookieDomain` to `none`

Read more about this here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#customizeTracker

Answer (score -1):

Actually this is the solution:

```
ga('send', {'hitType': 'timing', 
            'timingCategory': 'Category', 
            'timingVar': 'Load', 
            'timingValue': 120, 
            'timingLabel': 'Time to Load'});
```

Please, adjust your values accordingly.

Comment: seems to be missing a closing parenthesis

Comment: That's how to record User Timings but the question above pertains to Site Speed.