# Google analytics analytics.js giving average page load time as zero

Tags: universal-analytics, page-load-time, google-analytics-firebase

I have been trying to use `analytics.js` to track my `average page load time` under `Behaviour --> Site Speed --> Page Timings`. I am using (as already mentioned) `analytics.js` i.e Universal Analytics instead of `ga.js` i.e Classic Analytics since that is what is recommended in the documentations. I am tracking it for my `localhost` application

My issue is that the `average page load time` is not being reflected at all, although `'pageview'` is reflected properly. It shows a `zero` for all pages across the application.

This is the script that I included for the analytics

```
<script>

  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-Y', {'cookieDomain': 'none', 'siteSpeedSampleRate': 100});  //cookie domain is none since I am testing in localhost -- siteSpeedSampleRate set to 100 is the code I included for tracking page load time
  ga('send', 'pageview');
  ga('send', {    //Code to send UserTiming
  'hitType': 'event',
  'timingCategory': 'category',
  'timingVar': 'lookup',
  'timingValue': '123',
  'timingLabel': 'myUserTime'
});     
</script>
```

As mentioned in the comments, cookie domain is `none` since I am testing in localhost and `siteSpeedSampleRate set to 100` is the code I included for tracking page load time as suggested in the documentation. I am also sending the User Timing as suggested in the documentation [of analytics.js User Timings](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-timings)

My questions are :

1. What should I do to get the average page load time of each page. I searched a lot and am not being to get the proper javascript snippet.
2. I included the user timing javascript snippet a two days later than I included the '`pageview`'. So is it like it will take some time to get reflected in the analytics dashboard? If so, how much time.

Please help me get a clearer idea. Thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901187/how-to-set-up-page-speed-logging-for-google-analytics-in-analytics-js) helped me solve my problem. I just reemoved the cookieDomain here and changed the line to this

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-Y', {'siteSpeedSampleRate': 100});
```

Comment: It starts reflecting in real time.