# Why does Avg. Page Load Time is Zero on Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have recently connected to GA to track usage and my site view would less than 1000 views per day. I would like to see my site "Avg. Page Load Time" but it is always showing zero. What needs to done to get Avg. Page Load Time ?

I have referred [How to set up page speed logging for google analytics in analytics.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901187/how-to-set-up-page-speed-logging-for-google-analytics-in-analytics-js) but i don't have permission to Modify the GA code in the site. Is there any other option to get Avg. Page Load Time ?

Question:

Please see below that got Avg. Page Load Time for first landing page but remaining pages still 0 and my question is When will get Avg. Page Load Time for remaining pages(Please give me example to any one page) ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution to obtain a statistically significant value (or as much as possible in Google Analytics) is that of the link you entered.

10.000 page views should surely show data even with the default setting (1%).

To understand if the data you will be looking at makes sense, create a custom report with *dimension* **Browser** and *metrics* **Avg Page Load Time (sec)** and **Page Load sample** like this:

[image]

In this way you see if the sample is low, so the data is not very reliable.

This is the example for your second question (directly from Demo Account of Google Merchandise Store):

[image]

About your new screenshot: if you try to create a custom report with **Avg. Page Load Time** and **Page Load Sample** you will see that for that pages (with Avg. Page Load Time equals 0) the sample is 0, so the page load time cannot be calculated.

Comment: Total number of page view is just 5700 only, it would take two more weeks to reach 10,000 view. So after that it would show avg.page views for all the pages. But now seeing "2 of pageviews sent page load sample" but not for all the pages.

Comment: Need more traffic or modify the sample rate... the aren't any other solutions.

Comment: What is "10.000 page views should surely show data even with the default setting (1%)." ? Is this total number of page view or each and every page should reach 10.000 ?

Comment: It was a generic example, obviously it depends on how the page views are distributed. Considers that the maximum number of timing hits that will be processed per property per day is the greater of 10,000 or 1% of the total number of page views processed for that property that day. For small sites you need to be patient and always consider Page Load sample in the context.

Comment: Thank you. I have shared screen shot of GA. Please give me an example with any page view as per screenshot.

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot taken from Demo Account of Google Merchandise Store.

Comment: Thank you. Just updated another screenshot. I got avg.load time for first page and How many view still needed for second page(page-view 844) to get avg load time ? This question based my screenshot in the question section .

Comment: Try to create a custom report with Avg. Page Load Time and Page Load Sample. You will see that for that page the sample is 0, so the page load time cannot be calculated.